Error (10200): Verilog HDL Conditional Statement error at top_module.v(12): cannot match operand(s)
I have three versions of a code. Some syntax errors are coming in two versions of code. Can someone helps in understanding what causes these syntax issues...
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input areset,  // async active-high reset to zero
    input load,
    input ena,
    input [3:0] data,
    output reg [3:0] q); 
    always@(posedge clk or posedge areset)
        begin
            if(areset)
                q<=0;
            if(load | ena) // This is line 12
                begin
            q[3]<=(0 & (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[3]) ;
            q[2]<=(q[3]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[2]) ;
            q[1]<=(q[2]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[1]) ;
            q[0]<=(q[1]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[0]) ;
                end
           else
              q<=q;
            
        end
    
endmodule

This above code caused an error:

Error (10200): Verilog HDL Conditional Statement error at
top_module.v(12): cannot match operand(s)

module top_module(
    input clk,
    input areset,  // async active-high reset to zero
    input load,
    input ena,
    input [3:0] data,
    output reg [3:0] q); 
    always@(posedge clk) // This is different from the 1st code sample
        begin
            if(areset)
                q<=0;
            if(load | ena) 
                begin
            q[3]<=(0 & (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[3]) ;
            q[2]<=(q[3]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[2]) ;
            q[1]<=(q[2]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[1]) ;
            q[0]<=(q[1]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[0]) ;
                end
           else
              q<=q;
            
        end
    
endmodule

This above one doesn't cause the error.
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input areset,  // async active-high reset to zero
    input load,
    input ena,
    input [3:0] data,
    output reg [3:0] q); 
    always@(posedge clk or posedge areset)
        begin
            if(areset)
                q<=0;
            else if(load | ena)  // This is different from the 1st code sample
                begin
            q[3]<=(0 & (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[3]) ;
            q[2]<=(q[3]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[2]) ;
            q[1]<=(q[2]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[1]) ;
            q[0]<=(q[1]& (~load) & ena)  | (load & data[0]) ;
                end
           else
              q<=q;
            
        end
    
endmodule

And this one is also not causing the error.

From a Verilog language standpoint, there is no syntax error in the first code sample.
However, from a synthesis standpoint, there is an error.  A requirement of synthesis is that your code must match specific patterns so that the synthesis tool can map the the behavioral code to supported logic gates. The following pattern does not match anything that your synthesis tool maps to:
always@(posedge clk or posedge areset)
    begin
        if(areset)
            q<=0;
        if(load | ena) 

The 2nd code sample is supported because you removed posedge areset from the sensitivity list:
always@(posedge clk)

The 3rd code sample is also supported because you changed the if to an else if:
        else if(load | ena) 

Refer to synthesizable constructs for a discussion.  Your synthesis tool documentation should also discuss supported syntax.
